# Declaring an attribute for a different namespace in XML Schema

Tags: xsd, xml-namespaces

I've been using an XML format that is a mix of different existing formats and some custom elements and attributes, and I thought I should write a schema for those custom bits.

One thing I do is use custom attributes on elements in existing formats, like this:

```xml
<ns1:something attA="b" attB="a" ns2:extraAtt="c"/>
```

I understand that doing this is allowed but I cannot think how to declare my "extraAtt" in XML Schema or, worse, in a DTD.

I have tried reading the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/), but it could just as well be written in Chinese as far as I am concerned. Most tutorials talk only about "name", "type", and "use", e.g. [this one](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Tutorials/XmlSchemas/XsdTutorial_01.aspx) and [that one](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_simple_attributes.asp).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each schema document defines components (pieces of a schema) for one namespace.  So to define your attribute `ns2:extraAtt` you want a schema document something like this one:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://example.com/my-ns2">
  <xs:attribute name="extraAtt" type="xs:anySimpleType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

The declaration of element ns1:something will need to allow for this attribute somehow, either with an attribute reference (`<xs:attribute ref="ns2:extraAtt"/>`) or with an attribute wildcard (`<xs:anyAttribute namespace="http://example.com/my-ns2"/>` or similar).

---

Sorry about the legibility of the spec; it's a long story, but essentially some members of the WG did not think people like you exist ("no one except implementors reads the spec, and as long as they don't complain it's readable enough" -- at least, that was what they said before some implementors did complain, loudly and bitterly; then they just changed the subject).

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'm a bit disappointed though that my XML documents cannot be valid if the authors of the schema for ns1 didn't have the foresight of allowing extensions. ;-) If the format of ns1 is defined in a DTD only, which as far as I know doesn't have an equivalent to xs:anyAttribute, does that make my documents valid or invalid? (I hope I'm making sense.)

Comment: The definer of a term gets to say what it means.  The definer of the element ns1:something gets to say what they want to count as a valid instance.  The term *valid* is a technical term describing the relation of a document to a given schema; DTD validity is defined in terms of schemas written in DTD notation, XSD validity in terms of XSD schemas; neither caters for mixed-schema-language validation.  Whether that matters to you depends on why you want the document to be valid.

Comment: How to constraint this ns2:extraAtt attribute to use only in <ns1:something> elements?

Answer (score 1):

To declare just the attribute you can use this XSD:

```
<xs:schema 
  targetNamespace="theNamespaceUri"
  elementFormDefault="qualified"
  attributeFormDefault="qualified"
  xmlns="theNamespaceUri"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:attribute name="extraAtt" type="xs:string">
  </xs:attribute>

</xs:schema>
```

(assuming `extraAtt` is a simple string - you can use any type, or restrict an existing type etc.)