# XML schema two identical name of elements

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following structure of XML document.

```
<dane>
     <pojazd id="Pe206" marka="Peugeot"/>
</dane>

<oferta>
      <pojazd idPojazd="Pe206" kraj="Francja"/>
</oferta>
```

How can I add the namespaces to differentiate subelement named pojazd for element dane and element oferta?

Comment: Are you sure you really want/need to put them in different namespaces? If so, why? - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a task to put the element named pojazd into element dane and element oferta, so in the definition of xsd would is a conflict. I thought that different namespaces assigned to pojazd would solve this.

Comment: You can solve that problem more easily with local element declarations - an `<xs:element name="x">` appearing within an `<xs:complexType>`.

Comment: Ok I solved this issue by declaring for elements with the same name different types '<xsd:complexType>' in xsd document. Thanks for advice;)

Answer (score 0):

It could be like this:

```
<root xmlns:dane="http://host/dane" xmlns:oferta="http://host/oferta">
    <dane>
         <dane:pojazd id="Pe206" marka="Peugeot"/>
    </dane>
    <oferta>
          <oferta:pojazd idPojazd="Pe206" kraj="Francja"/>
    </oferta>
</root>
```

Comment: The definition of XML Schema should be that like below?
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   xmlns:dane="http://host/dane"
    xmlns:oferta="http://host/oferta">
</xsd:schema>

Comment: Hum... the semicolons are too many. Anyway, to properly reference your custom namespaces in a XSD, you should lookup other replies. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598558/declaring-an-attribute-for-a-different-namespace-in-xml-schema

Comment: This is ok, but in the first subelement pojazd the attribute id is key so defined as '<xsd:key>' and in the second subelement pojazd the attribute idPojazd is foreign key so defined as '<xsd:keyref>'. In this situation the validator show me this **Duplicate key value [pojazd] declared for identity constraint of element schema**. Shoud I add something else to resolve conflict?

Comment: Please post the XSD.